# How to return index as a negative

Tags: c#

I created a player class and made a array from that class for my menu driven player system I am trying to create a player. My ProcessCreate method is suppose to check the insert index returned from InsertPlayer and display the “successfully created” message if it is not equal to -1 but I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to get my GetInsertIndex method to return -1 and not throw a index out if range exception on InsertPlayer when the user enters a negative number or has a empty string

any help would be appreciated

Here is the part of my ProcessCreate method where it checks for -1

```
 playerindex = InsertPlayer(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, players, ref playerCount);


                     if (playerindex != -1 || playerCount > 0)
                     {


                             Console.WriteLine("\n{0,7}   {1,-20}{2, -20}{3,8}{4,8}{5,8}\n", "Number", "First Name", "Last Name", "Goals", " Assists", "Points");
                             Console.WriteLine("{0,7}   {1,-20}{2, -20}{3,8}{4,8}{5,8}",
                             players[playerindex].Number, players[playerindex].FirstName, players[playerindex].LastName,
                             players[playerindex].Goals, players[playerindex].Assists, players[playerindex].Points());
                             Console.WriteLine("Sucessfully created!");
                             Console.WriteLine();


                     }     

            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: the player number already exists");
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("\nCreate Player: the player roster is already full");

    }
```

> Here is my InsertPlayer and GetInsertIndex method

```
    static Int32 InsertPlayer(Int32 number, String firstName, String lastName, Int32 goals, 
    Int32 assists, Player[] players, ref Int32 playerCount)
{

        Int32 insertIndex, shiftCount;

        insertIndex = GetInsertIndex(number, players, ref playerCount);
        for (shiftCount = playerCount; shiftCount > insertIndex; shiftCount--)
            players[shiftCount] = players[shiftCount - 1];


            try
            {
                players[insertIndex] = new Player(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            if (insertIndex != -1)
            {
                playerCount++;
            }

            return insertIndex;
 }

    static Int32 GetInsertIndex(Int32 number, Player[] players,
 ref Int32 playerCount)
{
    Int32 index = 0;
    bool found = false;
    while (index < playerCount && found == false)

        if (players[index].Number > number || playerCount <= 0)
        {
            found = true;
            index = -1;
        }
        else
            index++;
    return index;
}
```

Comment: Well, you can't use a negative value to index an array, so not sure what you are trying to do, or what line is throwing the error.

Comment: I think the problem is this line: if (playerindex != -1 || playerCount > 0) You probably want && instead of ||

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to return a -1 dont worry about returning a -1 index as you say. just return -1; inside your exception.

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    insertIndex = -1;
    // or
    return -1;    
}
```

Though I suggest for checking to see if the string is blank and catching the error yourself and returning -1;

Answer (score 1):

You should very much consider change the array of players to using a `List<Player>` instead as lists provide a lot of the functions that you need.

You could eliminate `GetInsertIndex` if you rewrite `InsertPlayer` like this:

```
static int InsertPlayer(int number, string firstName, string lastName,
    int goals, int assists, List<Player> players)
{
    var index = -1;
    if (!players.Any(p => p.Number == number))
    {
        var player = new Player(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists);
        index = players.FindLastIndex(x => x.Number < number) + 1;
        players.Insert(index, player);
    }
    return index;
}
```

This code returns `-1` if the player number already exists in the list and otherwise it adds the new player at the correct position and then returns the new index.

Please avoid using `catch (Exception e)` - that just makes debugging very hard and doesn't really improve your code.

Also, avoid using `ref` like the plague. They are very rarely required. The fact that you're passing it around says that you've pre-allocated a large `players` array so as to avoid resizing it. Well `List<Player>` handles all the resizing for you and allows you to use `players.Count` at anytime.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't read your whole code, but since your players list is in actual array, can't you just do something like:

```
            Player player = new Player();
            try
            {
                player = new Player(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists);
                //or assign individually instead of using the constructor
                //if your player class allows it
                players[insertIndex] = player;

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
```

Then return:

```
    return Array.IndexOf(players,player);
```

It will return the index if it's there, or a -1 if it isn't